# TYPO3 Fluid check date format

Tags: typo3, fluid

I get a specific date format (Y-m-d) and want to check if only the year is given in fluid.

Basically you type "2017-00-00" in the backend and the output should be "2017".

I thought about something like this:

```
<f:if condition="{f:format.date(date: 'Y-00-00' format: 'Y-m-d')}">
        <f:then>
            <f:format.date format="%d.">{history.date}</f:format.date>
        </f:then>
        <f:else>
            <f:format.date format="%d. %B %Y">{history.date}</f:format.date>
        </f:else>
</f:if>
```

But is doesn't work. How can I achieve this?

Comment: How is this field configured in TCA? Is this a plain text field or a valid date (real datetime) or integer field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is just a plain text field (string), you can use the [v:format.substring helper](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/1.6.0/Format/SubstringViewHelper.html) and compare the last part of the string:

```
<f:if condition="{v:format.substring(content:history.date, start:4, length:7)} == '-00-00'">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missing `,` in date Inline notation. Try this.

```
<f:if condition="{f:format.date(date: 'Y-00-00', format: 'Y-m-d')}">
        <f:then>
            <f:format.date format="%d.">{history.date}</f:format.date>
        </f:then>
        <f:else>
            <f:format.date format="%d. %B %Y">{history.date}</f:format.date>
        </f:else>
</f:if>
```